# Automating folder creation in Django static directory

Tags: django

Mine is a very general question. I am planning a project for a client in django2 which will involve taking photos and uploading images to a media folder in the static directory.

Every time the client starts a project lets say 'project_A' they will generate a new record that will essentially populate the models via associated forms.  At some points, each record will have associated image files.  I think it is better to store image files separately (perhaps as in static/media/project_A/image_one.jpg ) and save an associated file name in the database. is that the best practice?

And if so is there a way to automate the creation of the folder "project_A" in the static folder when the client initiates the project?

Comment: You can specify `upload_to=` to specify the target filename. If the directory does not (yet) exists, Django will automatically create one.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify where to upload the image to by specifying a callable in the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). For example:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

def upload_image_to(instance, filename):
    return '{}/{}'.format(instance.project.name, filename)

class Image(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_to)
```

Comment: much appreciated folks thanks 3.28 am will trying it tomorrow